# Accessing the WebSession in @WebFluxTest

Tags: spring-webflux

I have a controller like so:

```
@RestController
public class ApiController {
    @GetMapping(path = "/somethings")
    public Mono<String> getThings(final WebSession webSession) {
        if (!webSession.getAttribute("state").equals("started")) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Cannot make API calls until session has started");
        }

        // Make api calls here...
    }
}
```

In my @WebFluxTest I need to access the web session to set the "state" attribute to "started".

Is there a way of accessing and updating the WebSession in an @WebFluxTest?

Answer (score 3):

Found an answer.

WebTestClient has a **mutateWith** method within which you can pass **WebTestClientConfigurer**.

By creating a custom WebTestClientConfigurer one can add session attributes.

```
public class SessionMutator implements WebTestClientConfigurer {

    private static Map<String, Object> sessionMap;

    private SessionMutator(final Map<String, Object> sessionMap) {
        this.sessionMap = sessionMap;
    }

    public static SessionMutator sessionMutator(final Map<String, Object> sessionMap) {
        return new SessionMutator(sessionMap);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterConfigurerAdded(final WebTestClient.Builder builder,
                                     final WebHttpHandlerBuilder httpHandlerBuilder,
                                     final ClientHttpConnector connector) {
        final SessionMutatorFilter sessionMutatorFilter = new SessionMutatorFilter();
        httpHandlerBuilder.filters(filters -> filters.add(0, sessionMutatorFilter));
    }

    public static ImmutableMap.Builder<String, Object> sessionBuilder() {
        return new ImmutableMap.Builder<String, Object>();
    }

    private static class SessionMutatorFilter implements WebFilter {
        @Override
        public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain webFilterChain) {
            return exchange.getSession()
                           .doOnNext(webSession -> webSession.getAttributes().putAll(sessionMap))
                           .then(webFilterChain.filter(exchange));
        }
    }
}
```

Then in @WebFluxTest one can do the following:

```
webTestClient.mutateWith(sessionMutator(sessionBuilder().put("sessionKey", "sessionValue").build()))
```

Comment: This issue is thrown https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/9257

Comment: Thanks, working as expected. Make sure we have `AutoConfigureWebTestClient` and `IntegrationTest` (from jhipster) class level annotation are present.